# Getting output in different language in GeoPy

Tags: nominatim, reverse-geocoding, internationalization, geopy

I am using django-cities and GeoPy. I am trying to get city name, id and country name, id based on given latitude and longitude.

Normally this is how you can get city and country using GeoPy.

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='test', timeout=3)
location = geolocator.reverse('52.5094982,13.3765983')
loc_dict = location.raw
print(loc_dict['address'])
```

and this is the output:

```
{'suburb': 'Tiergarten', 'country_code': 'de', 'country': 'Deutschland', 'postcode': '10117', 'attraction': 'Potsdamer Platz', 'road': 'Potsdamer Platz', 'city': 'Berlin', 'city_district': 'Mitte', 'state': 'Berlin'}
```

In Django this is how I'm trying to get them.

Normally it should work, my problem is that GeoPy returns country: Deutschland whereas in django-cities it's Germany. And this happens to cities as well, GeoPy gives me București and django-cities Bucharest.

How can i get city name and country name like in django-cities? If i get the name like in django-cities i can get the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.reverse), you can specify the language as a [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) type in the parameters of the `reverse()` method. By default it is `language=False`, that matches the language of the country for which the geocoder is applied, request for Ukraine => response in Ukrainian, for Netherlands => in Dutch etc.

> Preferred language in which to return results. Either uses standard
> [RFC2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) accept-language string or a simple comma-separated list of
> language codes.
>
> New in version 1.0.0.

Let's emphasis that it must be written in lower case.

So, this request

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='test', timeout=3)
location = geolocator.reverse('52.5094982,13.3765983', language='en')
print(location.raw)
```

leads to this

```
{'place_id': 194316915, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 404598740, 'lat': '52.5094969779106', 'lon': '13.376577040484365', 'display_name': 'Potsdamer Platz, Tiergarten, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Germany', 'address': {'road': 'Potsdamer Platz', 'suburb': 'Tiergarten', 'borough': 'Mitte', 'city': 'Berlin', 'state': 'Berlin', 'postcode': '10117', 'country': 'Germany', 'country_code': 'de'}, 'boundingbox': ['52.5094194', '52.5095951', '13.3765714', '13.3765815']}
```

where specifically `'country': 'Germany'` inside the `'address'` key.

Comment: it still returns Deutschland

Comment: it is in english, the only thing is that instead of Deutschland i want Germany, instead of Danmark i want Denmark, it seems it return every city and country exactly how they are written in their languange

Comment: @NitaAlexandru Try with lower case language code  (see updated answer)